# Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions Theorem 1.22(Fubini's Theorem)

Tags: measure-theory

I just can't understand the last sentence of step 2 in the proof of Fubini Theorem.

$\mu$ be a measure on X,$ \nu$ be a measure on Y.

$P_{0}:=\{A\times B|A \quad\mu-measurable ,B \quad \nu-measurable \}$

$P_{1}:=\{\cup^{\infty}_{j=1}S_{j}|S_{j}\in P_{0}\}$

It says that every set in $ P_{1} $ is a countable disjoint union of sets in $P_{0}$.But I think it maybe an uncountble union of sets in $P_{0}$.Because after we decompose the former n-1 rectangle in to $a_{n-1}$ disjoint rectangle the n_th recangle can theoretically generate $2a_{n-1}+1$ rectangle(suppose it joints with all $a_{n-1}$ rectangle).That means it has $2^{X}$(X is countble) cardinality which is uncountble. Thanks.

Comment: It's a little hard to parse what you are asking, but I think you need to distinguish between the elements of $P_1$ and $P_1$ itself. $P_1$ may be uncountable as a set, but each element of $P_1$ is defined to be a countable union.

Comment: It is defined as countable union of $P_{0}$.But not disjoint countable union of $P_{0}$.

Comment: The thing I am not sure is weather a countable union of sets in $P_{0}$ can be writen as a disjoint countable union of  sets in $P_{0}$.